# Return to previous if statement in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is my adventure game in c++. I have played around with it trying new things to improve the efficiency of it. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of setting up the levels? As of right now I just define the levels as strings and it seems way more inefficient than it needs to be. Especially with the if-statments, those are clustered.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string name;
    short choice;
    string choice2;

    int health = 100;

    // handling errors
    string nope = "Are you H@CK3R, that command does not exist";

    // handling directions
    string west = "You went West. ";
    string east = "You went East. ";
    string south = "You went South. ";
    string north = "Your went North. ";

    // Handles the areas of the map

    // Level 1
    string north1 = "You are now standing in an empty clearing. There is a path going North, East, and West.";
    string south1 = "You are now back where you started.";
    string east1 = "There is nothing of significance this way.";
    string west1 = "You see smoke off farther west. There is also a path to your North.";

    // level 2
    string north2 = "You have continued North, the trees are getting more thick. There is no longer a trail to the East and West.";
    string south2 = "You are now back in the empty clearing.";
    string east2 = "You cannot go this way.";
    string west2 = "You cannot go this way.";

    // level 3

    // level 4

    // level 5

    // level 6

    // level 7

    // level 8

    // level 9

    // level 10

    system("clear");
    std::cout << "Please enter your name.\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " to the [place holder]" << endl;
    cout << "Type 1 to start, press 2 for credits, press 3 to quit." << endl;
    std::cin >> choice;

    // main game block
    switch (choice) {
            system("clear");
        case 1:
            system("clear");
            while(1) {
            cout << "You wake up on a beach, there are trees to your North, and open beach to your East and West." << endl;
            cin >> choice2;
            if (choice2 == "north") {
                system("clear");
                while(2) {
                    cout << north << north1 << endl;
                    cin >> choice2;
                    if(choice2 == "north"){
                    system("clear");
                    cout << north << north2 << endl;
                    cin >> choice2;
                    } else if("south") {
                    cout << south << south2 << endl;
                        break;
                    } else if("east") {
                        cout << east << east2 << endl;
                        break;
                    } else if("west") {
                        cout << west << west2 << endl;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        system("clear");
                        cout << nope << endl;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }else if (choice2 == "south") {
                system("clear");
                cout << south << south1 << endl;
                cin >> choice2;
                break;
            }else if (choice2 == "east") {
                system("clear");
                cout << east << east1 << endl;
                cin >> choice2;
                break;
            }else if (choice2 == "west") {
                system("clear");
                cout << west << west1 << endl;
                cin >> choice2;
                break;
            } else if (choice2 == "hacker") {
                system("clear");
                cout << "nope";
                break;
            }else {
                system("clear");
                cout << nope << endl;
            }
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            system("clear");
            cout << "The Village Part 2" << endl;
            cout << "Coded ----- Kyle Sherman" << endl;
            cout << "Coded ----- Phillip Noble" << endl;
            cout << "Story ----- Pillip Noble" << endl;
            cout << "Story ----- Kyle Sherman" << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
    }
    cout << endl;
    /**
    // Handles displaying the stats and help
    if(choice2 == "help") {
        cout << "List of commands" << endl;
        cout << "stats ----- Display the stats" << endl;
        cout << "clear ----- Clears the screen" << endl;
        cout << "north ----- Goes North" << endl;
        cout << "south ----- Goes South" << endl;
        cout << "east ------ Goes East" << endl;
        cout << "west ------ Goes West" << endl;
    }else if(choice2 == "stats") {
        system("clear");
        cout << name << "'s health: " << health << endl;
    }else if(choice2 == "clear") {
        system("clear");
    }
     **/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One simple solution would be GOTO, if I understood your problem good enough.

MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34dt9cd.aspx

Comment: try looking at a Scanner implementation in C. It works in similar way: Loop & Switch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the GOTO statement is awesome. Are there any more efficient ways of doing this?

Comment: You can use GOTO, but this is a really BAD way to do it and I don't recommend it.

Comment: inb4 anti-goto zealots

Comment: On a side note; else if("south") is not a good one, should be else if(choice2 == "south")

Comment: Answering: declare a struct named `Place`, with a description and 4 `Place*` (a null ptr is a "you can't" case). Define all the places and set up the pointers beetween them at the start. No more "levels". One single loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a Chain of Responsibility design pattern.
Go read about it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility_pattern

You will be able to do condition check in a circular way, by setting the first element of the chain as the next element of the last element of the chains.